# Пакетное скачивание картинок без расширения

Tags: php, парсер

Нужно пакетно скачать по списку перечень изображений с сохранением имени, проблема в том, что у изображений отсутствуют расширения. Прошу подсказать по возможности.

Подходят варианты с десктопа, php. Пример ссылки:

```
https://i.siteapi.org/e46vxodARyBwhQBo6NkbFQ8xwgE=/fit-in/1024x768/center/top/78478838e383d62.s.siteapi.org/img/2i305r2gr2yo4k0c8gw8sc80skkco0
```

Comment: wget -i имя_файла_с_урлами

Comment: Та же проблем с тем же сайтом. Решили?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$url='https://i.siteapi.org/e46vxodARyBwhQBo6NkbFQ8xwgE=/fit-in/1024x768/center/top/78478838e383d62.s.siteapi.org/img/2i305r2gr2yo4k0c8gw8sc80skkco0';
stream_context_set_default(
    array(
        'http' => array(
          'header' => 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)',
        )
    )
);
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
$mime_types = array(
  'image/png'  => 'png',
  'image/jpeg' => 'jpg',
  'image/gif'  => 'gif',
  'image/bmp'  => 'bmp',
);
$ext =  $mime_types [ $headers['Content-Type'] ]
?>
```